# Dragging back to fire an arrow in SpriteKit/Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am creating an iOS application using SpriteKit in which two archers are placed at random x-positions in the GameScene. After the scene loads, the camera focuses on the archer places to the left side of the scene. From here, I want the user to be able to press down on the screen, "pull back", and release their finger in order to fire an arrow at an angle and level of power relative to how far back and at what angle the user moved their finger and ultimately let go (think the firing action in Angry Birds in which the player drags their finger back and releases, firing the bird in the opposite direction). I am curious how to derive an angle (opposite of the pulled-back direction) and level of power from the touch the user made within my application. I do not need a full explanation, but maybe a few tips or resources which may speak on a similar function in SpriteKit, or maybe point me to a method which deals with this sort of user interaction. My experience with SpriteKit has been limited mostly to simple touches but not anything as advanced as dragging to create said firing data. Any tips/help is appreciated. Thanks.

-David

Answer (score 1):

Use the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` methods to determine the 'line' that the player dragged their finger over. Use these start and end points and some basic trigomonetry to determine the angle and length of the line.

These form your angle and strength of firing. You can then add some simple graphics effects (e.g. if you continually re-calculate the current line in `touchesMoved`, you can rotate the sprite for the bow to the current angle etc).

Comment: He would would also need to use touchesMoved to track how far back , or how much tension, the player is pulling back .

Comment: I don't think so - `touchesEnded` is also passed the location of the touch, so you just need the start of the line from `touchesBegan` and the end from touchesEnded`. Or vice-versa, as the vector will be from the touchesEnded location to the touchesBegan location. The length of the vector is the tension. touchesMoved would be used to dynamically draw a graphical representation of the vector.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the feedback guys. I figured I should use touchesBegan/touchesEnded/touchesMoved but wasn't entirely sure if this is the best way. I'll try to figure something out and let you guys know.